# OnPreviewFrame(IntPtr data, Camera camera) is not being called | FastAndroidCamera

Tags: android, android-camera

I am trying to access the frames of the preview on Android using this Library, and then passing the FastJavaByteArray to Zxing's Decode() method to scan for a barcode in a specific area of the preview. The preview is working fine, and when I use the normal Preview.SetPreviewCallback(this); it works fine and the OnPreviewFrame(byte[], Camera) gets called. It's just when I use Preview.SetNonMarshalingPreviewCallback(this) that the method isn't being called. I'm not to sure why this is happening and I wanted to use this so I could scan for a barcode frame by frame using Zxing. I've attached my code below.

```
public void Open() {
            if (!closed) return;
        try {
                Preview = Camera.Open();
            }
            catch (Exception e) {
                Console.WriteLine(e);
            }

            var parameters = Preview.GetParameters();

            int numBytes = (parameters.PreviewSize.Width * parameters.PreviewSize.Height * Android.Graphics.ImageFormat.GetBitsPerPixel(parameters.PreviewFormat)) / 8;
            using (FastJavaByteArray buffer = new FastJavaByteArray(numBytes))
                Preview.AddCallbackBuffer(new FastJavaByteArray(numBytes));

            var options = new ZXing.Mobile.MobileBarcodeScanningOptions();
            options.PossibleFormats.Add(BarcodeFormat.QR_CODE);
            barcodeReader = options.BuildBarcodeReader();

            Preview.SetNonMarshalingPreviewCallback(this);
            //Preview.SetPreviewCallback(this);


            Handler handler = new Handler();
            Action loop = null;
            loop = () =>
            {
                if (!closed)
                {
                    AutoFocusLoop();
                    
                    handler.PostDelayed(loop, (long)(1000 * AF_DELAY));
                }
            };
            handler.Post(loop);

            closed = false;
        }

 public void OnPreviewFrame(IntPtr data, Camera camera)
        {
            throw new NotImplementedException();
        }
```